# CakePHP 2.1: Making a mock controller with Session::read()

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, mocking, phpunit

I am new to phpunit and unit testing in general. I am attempting to convert a large app to cakephp 2.0 and make unit tests for everything.

I am trying to create a mock object in which when, $this->Session->read('Auth.Account.id') is called, it returns 144... this will give an account with an id that has items.

however, I get an error as the Mock seems to be erroring out on other Session::read('AuthCode') calls in various beforeFilter calls;

***Expectation failed for method name is equal to when invoked 1 time(s)
Parameter 0 for invocation SessionComponent::read('AuthCode') does not match expected value.
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.***

Like I said I am new to phpunit and unit testing... what am I doing wrong?

```
class PagesController extends MastersController {
        public function support(){
        if($this->Session->read('Auth.Account.id')) {
            $items = $this->Account->Items->find('list', array('conditions'=>array('Items.account_id'=>$this->Session->read('Auth.Account.id'))));           
        }
        $this->set(compact('items'));
    }
}


class PagesControllerTestCase extends CakeTestCase {
        /**
     * Test Support
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testSupport() { 
        #mock controller
        $this->PagesController = $this->generate('Pages', array(
            'methods'=>array('support'),
            'components' => array(
                'Auth',
                'Session',
            ),
        ));

                #mock controller expects
        $this->PagesController->Session->expects(
            $this->once())
                ->method('read') #Session:read() method will be called at least once
                ->with($this->equalTo('Auth.Account.id')) #when read method is called with 'Auth.Account.id' as a param
                ->will($this->returnValue(144)); #will return value 144


        #test action
        $this->testAction('support');
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm I at least thinking correctly... is $this->PagesController->Session->expects($this->once())->method('read')->with('Auth.Account.id')->will($this->returnValue(144));  is suppose to return 144 when Session::read('Auth.Account.id') is called only once?  It's not suppose to fire when Session::read('AuthCode') is fired in a beforeFilter call... right? Like I said I am new to phpunit and unit testing in general, but I think it is supported to do this, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to just write the Sessions out manually. Like they do is the SessionComponentTest in the core.

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Test/Case/Controller/Component/SessionComponentTest.php

Answer (score 1):

You should access Auth session variables with the Auth component and not the Session component.

Instead of

`if($this->Session->read('Auth.Account.id')) {`

try

`if ($this->Auth->user('Account.id')) {`

Same goes for your Items::find call.

Mocking the Auth component is still the way to go.

`class PagesControllerTestCase extends CakeTestCase {`

should be

`class PagesControllerTestCase extends ControllerTestCase {`

and then in your test:

```
$PagesController = $this->generate('Pages', array(
    'methods'=>array('support'),
    'components' => array(
        'Auth' => array('user')
     ),
));

$PagesController->Auth->staticExpects($this->exactly(2))
    ->method('user')
    ->with('Account.id')
    ->will($this->returnValue(144));
```